# Use ERB block as a literal in Rouge syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, rouge

I'm trying to setup [Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge) for my Rails app and I'm having issues with passing in inline ERB strings or blocks. When it reads ERB from a file it works fine however. Here is an example of what I have -

**Works**

*rouge_helper.rb*

```
def rouge(file, language)
  formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTML.new(css_class: 'highlight', wrap: true)
  lexer     = Rouge::Lexer.find(language)
  output    = formatter.format(lexer.lex(file))

  output
end
```

*app/views/example/_partial.html.erb*

```
<p>hello <%= p "world" %></p>
```

*app/views/example/index.html.erb*

```
<pre class="highlight">
  <code>
    <%= raw rouge(File.read(Rails.root + "app/views/example/_partial.html.erb"), "erb") %>
  </code>
</pre>
```

**Does not work**

When I repleace the *index.html.erb* file with this -

```
<pre class="highlight">
  <code>
    <%= raw rouge("<p>hello <%= p 'world' %></p>", "erb") %>
  </code>
</pre>
```

I get this error -

> app/views/styleguide/index.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected '>' 
>   app/views/styleguide/index.html.erb:5: unknown regexp options - pr 
>   app/views/styleguide/index.html.erb:6: unterminated string meets end
>   of file  app/views/styleguide/index.html.erb:6: syntax error,
>   unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'

**Desired Result**

```
<p>hello <%= p "world" %></p>
```

Comment: `rouge("<%= p 'world' %>", "erb")`  should be `rouge(p('world'), "erb")`

Comment: @PGill I'm not trying print 'world', I'm trying to print an entire html.erb partial. I tweaked the question slightly so hopefully its more clear.